# Is there a Wordpress version that is incompatible with PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, comparison, compatibility

Is there some decent information available which WordPress versions do *not* support PHP 5.3? I mean the more recent ones like 2.9 / 3.0 / 3.1?

I'm only concerned about the Wordpress core codebase, not plugins. I've run WP for most of the time on PHP 5.3 now. But some servers are still on PHP 5.2 and some hosters are concerned if an upgrade might break something, so I try to gather some feedback from a larger community.

The [graphical wp.org stats](http://wordpress.org/about/stats/) do not differ between WP and PHP versions to each other, this would be some good source as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We run very large sites on WP 3+ and PHP 5.3.2. We've also upgraded from 5.2 without any issues.

Comment: Currently considering an upgrade from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x on my server, but it's true, there are relatively few reports of users' experiences running WordPress 3.3 on this version.

Would also like to hear from anyone that has been brave enough to use it in a production environment. More concerned with errors being thrown by the WP core and default themes, not so much with plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The more stat combinations [had been asked for](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/previously-wed-talked-about-putting-up/#comment-10456), but went nowhere. You can try to poke wordpress.org-related people again about that.

I think anything not coming from someone who has access to that data will be just anecdotal evidence.